# How to take user input and send it to a query in the same file?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this input form `<input type='hidden' name='thenumbers' id='thenumbers'>`, which is in a form with $_POST method. I'm trying to get the value of the input field, so I can send it to mySQL query in the same form `$result = $conn->query("SELECT nomeDepartamento from departamentos WHERE idEmpresas =   ")`. I am many hours trying... used $_GET and $_POST and nothing. Thank you for your help.

Here's the form:

```
<form action="includes/add.inc.php" method="post" id="editmodal" class="form-horizontal2">
   <div class="modal-body">
      <input type="hidden" name="update_id" id="update_id">
      <div class="form-row ">
         <div class="col">
            <!-- First name -->
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>Nome do funcionário</label>
               <input type="text" name="nomeFuncionario" id="nomeFuncionario" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o nome do funcionário">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>E-mail do funcionário</label>
               <input type="text" name="emailFuncionario" id="emailFuncionario" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o e-mail do funcionário">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>Senha do funcionário</label>
               <input type="password" name="senhaFuncionario" id="senhaFuncionario" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite a senha do funcionário">
            </div>
            <div id="demo" style="text-align: center"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
         <?php
            require 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
            $result = $conn->query("SELECT * from empresas") or die($conn->error);
            ?>
         <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="menu1" required="required">Escolha a empresa </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu myclass numberom1 thenumbers" aria-labelledby="menu1" name="thenumbers" required="required">
            <?php
               while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
            <li value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?> " class="dropdown-item"><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- Create a hidden input -->
      <input type='hidden' name='thenumbers' id='thenumbers'>
      <div class="dropdown">
         <?php
            require 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
            
            
            $result = $conn->query("SELECT nomeDepartamento from departamentos WHERE idEmpresas =   ") or die($conn->error);
            ?>
         <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="menu1" required="required" style="position: relative; left: 251px; top: -38px;">Escolha o departamento </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu myclass numberom1 thenumbers" aria-labelledby="menu1" name="thenumbers" required="required">
            <?php
               while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
            <li value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?> " class="dropdown-item"><?php echo $row['nomeDepartamento']; ?></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- Create a hidden input -->
      <input type='hidden' name='thenumbers' id='thenumbers'>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
         <button type="submit" name="addDataDep" class="btn btn-primary" id="addbtn1">Adicionar</button>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you share the code you currently have? How is the form defined?

Comment: Updated the post. Now it has the form code.

Comment: you want the ul li list of Escolha o departamento data based on input type hidden value based on select query?

Comment: The input value holds the id of what the user has chosen in the dropdown. I want to take that input value and send it to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it live you have to use XMLHttpRequest (Ajax) , there is a tutorial [link](http://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Check-User-Sign-Up-Name-Ajax-PHP-Social-Network-Tutorial) that checks if username exists in database , use this method and change it to your needs